# Novel re returning Jupiter astronauts find only two people alive

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for post-apocalyptic novel about astronauts return from Jupiter to find only one old man and one young girl alive; also something about Antarctica.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Good Morning, Midnight](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Good-Morning-Midnight-Lily-Brooks-Dalton/dp/0812998898) by Lily Brooks-Dalton.

The blurb mentions a trip to Jupiter, a post-apocalyptic theme and a scientist (and his mysterious young female companion) working in the Arctic when a catastrophic event occurs.

> Augustine, a brilliant, aging astronomer, is consumed by the stars.
>   For years he has lived in remote outposts, studying the sky for
>   evidence of how the universe began. At his latest posting, in a
>   research center in the Arctic, news of a catastrophic event arrives.
>   The scientists are forced to evacuate, but Augustine stubbornly
>   refuses to abandon his work. Shortly after the others have gone,
>   Augustine discovers a mysterious child, Iris, and realizes that the
>   airwaves have gone silent. They are alone.
>
> At the same time, Mission Specialist Sullivan is aboard the Aether on
>   its return flight from Jupiter. The astronauts are the first human
>   beings to delve this deep into space, and Sully has made peace with
>   the sacrifices required of her: a daughter left behind, a marriage
>   ended. So far the journey has been a success. But when Mission Control
>   falls inexplicably silent, Sully and her crewmates are forced to
>   wonder if they will ever get home.

[image]

Comment: @Dgbsoco - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accept" button (the tick below the arrows on the left-hand side of the page) to show that it's the correct answer.